# R condtional replace in a 3d array

Tags: r, arrays, replace, conditional-statements

I want to conditionally replace values in a specific vector in a 3d array, the replacement value being a value from a probability calculation.  For some reason the replacement value is the same for all values of the vector, rather than being calculated on an individual vector element basis. I must have something simple incorrect in my syntax

```
library (abind)
pop <- array(c (1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,2,3,5), dim = c(1,5,3))
pop <- abind(pop,pop, along = 1)
```

so the particular vector I want to work on is

```
pop[dim(pop)[1], ,1]

[1] 1 0 1 1 1
```

what I want to achieve is to leave the zero value alone, and if the value is one, then run a random binomial test, to see if it changes to zero, and if it does change, do the insertion.  I'm told that the ifelse is vectorized but with this syntax it is not operating individually on each element of the vector. When I try to produce a new vector as such

```
ifelse (pop[dim(pop)[1], ,1] == 1, rbinom(1,1,0.5), 0)
```

I get either no change

```
> ifelse (pop[dim(pop)[1], ,1] == 1, rbinom(1,1,0.5), 0)
[1] 1 0 1 1 1
```

or alternatively it changes all values.

```
> ifelse (pop[dim(pop)[1], ,1] == 1, rbinom(1,1,0.5), 0)
[1] 0 0 0 0 0
```

I'm expecting some of the values in the array to be changed, but not "all or nothing".  What am I doing wrong?  Also if there is a simple elegant way to do the substitution back into the original 3d array I'd be grateful. Thx. J

Answer (score 0):

I think I did find a solution using the "modify_if" function of the dplyr package.

```
pop[dim(pop)[1], ,1] %<>% modify_if(~ .x == 1, ~ rbinom(1,1,pliv1))
```

HTH, J